# sort function sorts tableviewcells wrong

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I try to sort the tableViewCells by their number (from lowest to highest) inside a label with this function:

```
        self.jobs.sort(by: {$0.location < $1.location})
```

In general, every cell get sorted correctly, but as soon a number is 0.00 it get's sorted as a higher number than 0.1.

How I format the number inside the label:

```
            let distance = myLocation.distance(from: jobLocation) / 1000
            self.distance.text = String(format: "%.01fkm", distance)
```

Comment: What is the type of `location`? Is it a numeric type or `String`? If it is a `String`, don't sort numeric Strings, sort the actual numbers stored as a numeric type (`Double`, `Int`, `Decimal` or whatever fits your needs).

Comment: location: String = "", could u may tell me how I can format a String into a Decimal?

Comment: Your `distance` variable (`let distance = myLocation.distance(from: jobLocation) / 1000`) already seems to be numeric, so you should use that instead of its formatted String version.

Comment: Could you please share the code, How do you create myLocation, or array where myLocation stored ?